# Create a method for a specific type

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Below are two lines of code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(filePath);
string k = xmlDoc.XmlToString();
```

What I want to do is:

Originally, there's no "XmlToString" method under the XmlDocument class, how can I create a method like this?

Comment: Use .OuterXml property

Comment: Or use extension if you want to add a new method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are referring to are extensions methods and you can create your own by creating a new static class to contain the method, then writing a new static method using the "this' modifier and your type  (XmlDocument) as the first parameter. E.G:

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
  public static string XmlToString(this XmlDocument doc)
  {
    return "....";
}
```

}

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.XmlToString();
}
```